# Align three control side by side in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget, alignment

I am new in Android
I wanna put controls like this,but I can't:

---

### textview1

### edittext1    edittext2   button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum = "1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background = "#faadadad" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Final"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "2dip"
        android:layout_marginTop = "1dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "1dip"
        android:id="@+id/edit1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "2dip"
        android:layout_marginTop = "1dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "1dip"
        android:id="@+id/edit2" />
</LinearLayout>
    <Button android:text = "grade:"
        android:layout_width = "0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "0.2"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

with above code , edittext1 and  edittext2 and textview2 shows out of screen and under the textview1

Comment: Add `android:orientation=vertical` in the first `LinearLayout`.

Comment: put your `textview` into your `LinearLayout` section.

Comment: @jakombo, I do that but shows like this: [textview1][textview2][button] , all of them in one line

Comment: Where's the 2nd EditText in the xml?

Comment: @Tarun ,I do that,but nothing happend

Comment: @SlumpA, I can't write it because ,when I put second EditText ,it shows out of screen.

Comment: you seem to be missing one edittext in the xml code as I only see one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this xml as example, just replace with your values

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum = "1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background = "#faadadad" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Final"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:hint="Search Terms" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:hint="Another" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="grade:" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

delete:

```
    android:weightSum = "1.0"
```

change:

```
    android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to vertical:

```
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

this is ok

```
    android:background = "#faadadad" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Final"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

change:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
```

to:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

ok:

```
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

delete:

```
        android:layout_weight="0.8">
```

ok:

```
        <EditText
```

change:

```
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

to:

```
            android:layout_width="0dp"
```

ok:

```
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

add:

```
            android:layout_weight="1"
```

ok:

```
            android:layout_marginLeft = "2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop = "1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom = "1dip"
            android:hint="Search Terms" />
```

Here you can try adding another EditText (copy paste)

delete:

```
    </LinearLayout>
```

ok:

```
    <Button android:text = "grade:"
        android:layout_width = "0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

change:

```
        android:layout_weight = "0.2"/>
```

to:

```
        android:layout_weight = "1"/>
```

add:

```
    </LinearLayout>
```

ok:

```
</LinearLayout>
```